# Match two strings based on common substring

Tags: perl

I have a list of files that needs to be grouped in pairs. (I need to append an HTML 'File B' (body) to 'File A' (header) because I need to serve them statically without server-side includes).

Example:

```
/path/to/headers/.../matching_folder/FileA.html
/someother/path/to/.../matching_folder/body/FileB.html
```

Emphasizing with the ellipses that the paths are not of uniform length, nor is 'matching folder' always in the same position in the path.

It seems I need to match/join based on the common substring 'matching_folder', but I am stumped on scanning each string, storing, matching (excerpt):

```
my @dirs = ( $headerPath, $bodyPath );

my @files = ();

find( { wanted => \&wanted, no_chdir => 1 }, @dirs );

foreach my $file (@files) {
# pseudocode: append $file[0] to $file[1] if both paths contain same 'matching_folder'
};

sub wanted {
return unless -f and /(FileA\.html$)|(FileB\.html$)/i;
push @files, $_;
};
```

Comment: Can't you search just for headers, and then for each of them check there's a body to attach?

Comment: The 'matching_folder' may be X, Y, Z, etc. and not have the same path length or position.

Comment: Not having the same position even if counted from the right?

Comment: Alas, no. Poorly-designed file system.

Comment: @sqldoug: How are the header and body files normally paired up?

Comment: @Borodin by using a proprietary include call, but the new system doesn't allow for includes at this time

Comment: @sqldoug: Wouldn't it be best to use that call to pair up the two files off line? Is it JavaScript code? I realise there may be a problem with the API, but I can't see something like that being too big to rewrite in Perl, especially if it is somehow data-driven.

Comment: Failing that, is there a limit to the number of intermediate directories in the path between `matching_folder` and `FileA` or `FileB`? If it's always `matching_folder/FileA.html` or `matching_folder/x/FileA.html` then the problem is relatively trivial

Comment: @Borodin Thanks; migrating from one system to another, so the old language can't be used (templating); the file paths are not always structured that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash the files by all the directory steps in their names.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use File::Find;

my $headerPath = 'headers';
my $bodyPath   = 'bodies';

my @dirs = ($headerPath, $bodyPath);
my @files;

sub wanted {
    return unless -f and /file.\.html$/;
    push @files, $_;
};

find({ wanted => \&wanted, no_chdir => 1 }, @dirs);

my %common;    
for my $file (@files) {
    my @steps = split m(/), $file;
    push @{ $common{$_} }, $file for @steps;
};

# All the headers and all the bodies share their prefixes,
# but that's not what we're interested in.
delete @common{qw{ bodies headers }};

for my $step (keys %common) {
    next if 1 == @{ $common{$step} };
    print "$step common for @{ $common{$step} }\n";
}
```

Tested on the following structure:

```
bodies/3/something/C/something2/fileA.html
bodies/2/junk/B/fileB.html
bodies/1/A/fileC.html
headers/a/B/fileD.html
headers/c/one/A/two/fileE.html
headers/b/garbage/C/fileF.html
```

Output:

```
B common for headers/a/B/fileD.html bodies/2/junk/B/fileB.html
C common for headers/b/garbage/C/fileF.html bodies/3/something/C/something2/fileA.html
A common for headers/c/one/A/two/fileE.html bodies/1/A/fileC.html
```

Answer (score 0):

With the above, I can get to

```
for my $step (keys %common) {
  next unless 2 == @{ $common{$step} }; # pairs
  my @pairs = @{ $common{$step} };
  my $html;
  foreach my $f (@pairs) {
    $html .= &readfile($f);
  };
  &writefile($html, $step . '.html');
}
```

And get what I need for now. Thanks all! (I love Perl, making hard things possible indeed).